# Using numpy to simplify functions

Tags: python

I am quite new to numpy. I was wondering if there is a easier way to run this code without using loops by using numpy.

```
def summer(n):
    list1 = []
    mysum = 0

    for i in range(1,n+1):#making a random number up to n in a list
        list1.append(random())
    for j in range(0,len(list1),2):
        mysum = mysum + (math.sin(list1[j]) * math.cos(list1[j+1]))
    return mysum
print(summer(100))
```

currently I have only found a good way to create the random list of numbers using:

```
rand = np.random.random(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's pretty straightforward in numpy, and certainly faster:

```py
def summer(n):
    return (np.sin(np.random.rand(int(n/2))) * np.sin(np.random.rand(int(n/2)))).sum()
```

Note that I split `list1` in 2 lists, as indices of `list1` were only used once and `list1` was an internal variable, it does not change the result.

*Edit:* If the question is about getting elements of an array with only odd or even indices, they can be obtained with `my_array[::2]` and `my_array[1::2]`.

Comment: That does almost exactly what i want it to do but I am not sure how to iterate it by two. In my original code j has a step size of 2 (0,2,4,6)

Comment: Right, but you used half of the indices (n/2) in the `cos`, and the other half on the `sin`. That's what I do here too.